# London Underground puzzle

Tags: graph-theory

This is something I have thought about during my commute through the London Underground.

Is it possible to make a trip through the London underground in such a way that:

> - You have to use all the lines.
> - You can use each line only once.
> - You can only make one stop before changing lines.
> - You cannot visit a station twice.

I don't actually know if this is possible and I haven't seen a question like this.
 I am quiet interested to see if this is possible.

Edit: The DLR and the London Overground are not included. To make the rules clear here is an example.

If I start at Baker Street I can take the Metropolitan line to Great Portland Street. I have only travelled one stop so I need to get off. From Great Portland Street I can get the Hammersmith and City line to Euston Square, but then I need to get off and get a different line.

Comment: Do you have to _stop_ at a station to count as _visiting_ it?

Comment: As the problem is stated, staying where you are does meet all requirements.

Comment: Is the aim to visit as many lines as possible? Or as many stations as possible? And is the DLR included? What about the London Overground lines?

Comment: Yes! The aim is to use as many lines as you can. The DLR and the Overground lines are not included. I should probably rephrase my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this works. The line used between each two stops is in brackets.

Oxford Circus (Victoria) Green Park (Picadilly) Picadilly Circus (Bakerloo) Charing Cross (Northern) Embankment (District) Westminster (Jubilee) Waterloo (Waterloo & City) Bank (Central) Liverpool Street (Circle) Moorgate (Metropolitan) Barbican (Hammersmith & City) Farringdon

edit: Map added as requested.

[image]

Comment: +1, but this answer would be *much* improved by a visual depiction. Maps of the London Underground network are easy to find online, and you could trace out your route to show how it works.